# Python Spyder Display Symbolic Math

Tags: python, ipython, symbolic-math, spyder

In Spyder 2 (Anaconda distribution) and in the IPython QT Console I'm able to print results of symbolic calculations (from an answer I got for a previous post) but I can't get equations in strings to print with the [a IPython's Rich Display System](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb):

```
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display, Math

init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

x, y, z = symbols('x y z')

#----- prints correctly
ii = integrate(x**2 + x + 1, x) 
display(ii)

#----- does not print
Math(r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx')
```

The above prints the results of the integrate correctly but the Math() does not print (no error -- just skips it). Note it all works in SciPy web notebook.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Math` class doesn't generate the rendered image from your Latex, that's why it doesn't work directly.

To get what you want you need to use this code

```
from IPython.display import Image, display
from IPython.lib.latextools import latex_to_png

eq = r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx'
data = latex_to_png(eq, wrap=True)
display(Image(data=data))
```

Then you will see the right image

Comment: Sorry, that means that you don't have Latex installed. But don't worry, for this to work you need either Latex or matplotlib. To make things work with the last one, just remove the `backend` keyword. I'm going to update the question to reflect it (just pay attention to the `data = ...` line)

Comment: Ok, I'll do the final update then :) Could you mark it as answered by clicking the green check sign after it? I'm also going to send IPython guys a pull request to make this work as it works in the notebook, i.e. by just using `Math(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Hello guys im still having the problem, whe i use

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display((Math(r'P(Purchase|Male)= \frac{Numero\ total\ de\ compras\ hechas\ por\ hombres\}{Total\ de\ hombres\ en\ el\ grupo\} = \frac{Purchase\cap Male}{Male}')))
```

on jupyter it works fine, but when i do the exact same code on spyder it doesnt work

im using python 3.6 , spyder 3.3.3

also i tried the marked asnwer but latex_to_png makes a NoneType Object on spyder

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open an issue about this in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and remove it as an answer here because it's not really an answer. Also, please note that you need to have Latex installed in your system for this to work.